# Hide Randomness in Ciphertext

Tags: encryption, randomness, steganography

**Ciphertext** has the property to appear **random**. As a matter of fact, randomness is the first test, an encryption algorithm must pass. However, there are various setups, which monitor the incoming/ outgoing traffic and can easily identify **Random Bits (ciphetext)**. Is there any technique/ research paper in literature which can disguise the randomness of ciphertext, making it less susceptible to identification? In other words, can a system be designed to introduced undetectable form of encryption?

**Note**:- I am fully aware of **steganography**, but I want to explore the chances of hiding randomness in the domain of Encryption.

Comment: Make all communications is encrypted. That is better and easier

Answer (score 2):

You can compute an $f(g(m))$ in which $g(m)$ is your encryption method and $f$ is a meaningful mapping function. As an example of $f$ I can mention a dictionary codebook mapping.

For example if your output is 11101000 you can see it as 1110 and 1000 then map 1110 to "apple" and 1000 to "grape". Your codebook here must consist of all inputs of 4 bits and the name of fruits as output.

In the receiver side, you must clearly first compute $f^{-1}$ and convert the name of fruits to predefined codes and then decrypt it.